# Match opposite of regular expression: "([a-z])\1{3,}"

Tags: regex

Can I specify a pattern and have everything else that doesn't fit the pattern to be matched?

Regex to match: I want to match something like this

I tried all ready this example:

```
"ffffffff".matches("([a-z])\1{3,}") = true
"fffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\1{3,}") = false
"asdffffffasdf".matches("([a-z])\1{3,}") = false
```

But whats the opposite way of this example? This one doesnt work `(?![a-z])\1{3,})`

I need such matches:

```
"ffffffff".matches(" ??? ") = false 
"fffffasdf".matches("(???") = true
"asdffffffasdf".matches("???") = true
```

Comment: What language are you using to achieve this? I don't recognize the syntax.

Comment: And what does it have to do with Joomla? In general, you can't use a regular expression for this, but you don't need to. Just negate the result of `matches()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!([a-z])\1{3,}$).*
```

Comment: Thank you very much, its working but i cant joing to this regex:(^12\d{14}$|^13\d{14}$)     its start with 12 or 13 + (14 Numbers but not 14 times same numbers)